I want to write in English, dutch and Hindi in the same document with babel
I have already have a set of code for writing document in English and dutch
\RequirePackage[dutch,English]{babel},
It tried incorporating hindi, but it is showing error.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

... also saying which error you get would be very helpful!

The language options are usually written in lower case, so english should be used instead of English to avoid an error message about unknown option English.

I want to add Hindi summary in my thesis, as indicated below in English
\chapter*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\setheader{Summary}
\Small\noindent\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{T}}he natural flows of rivers have been heavily modified in the process of development and economic growth across the basins of the world.
